# Grep Next Line and Modifying grep

Tags: bash

Still stuck on this one.

I need to use grep to search for the first line (ISSN) and it should be able to output 0007-9235

```
<td nowrap valign="top" align="right"><b>ISSN:</b></td>
<td valign="top"> 0007-9235 </td>
```

I had issued issn=$(grep "ISSN:" $i -A1) and out put is

```
<td nowrap valign="top" align="right"><b>ISSN:</b></td> <td valign="top"> 0007-9235 </td>
<td nowrap valign="top" align="right"><b>ISSN:</b></td> <td valign="top"> 0028-4793 </td>
<td nowrap valign="top" align="right"><b>ISSN:</b></td> <td valign="top"> 0009-2665 </td>
<td nowrap valign="top" align="right"><b>ISSN:</b></td> <td valign="top"> 0034-6861 </td>
<td nowrap valign="top" align="right"><b>ISSN:</b></td> <td valign="top"> 0028-0836 </td>
```

I need it to output only 0007-9235, the whole column below. Please help, thank you!

Comment: `for a in `ls RQ=RECORD\&rank=*.html && b in ...` is wrong and won't work.

Comment: Do you know how to get the ISSN result?

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your command to `cut`:

```
grep -Pzo '<td nowrap align="center" bgcolor="FFFFE1"><p align="center">[^>]*>\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?' $i | 
 cut -d ' ' -f1-2
```

Or use awk:

```
grep -Pzo '<td nowrap align="center" bgcolor="FFFFE1"><p align="center">[^>]*>\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?' $i | 
 awk '{print $1, $2}'
```

Comment: Can you show output of `grep -Pzo '<td nowrap align="center" bgcolor="FFFFE1"><p align="center">[^>]*>\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?' $i | cat -vte` in your question.

Comment: 162.500$ 107.740$ 27.760$ 3.1$ 5.4$
54.420$ 52.426$ 14.747$ 8.2$ 4.7$
45.661$ 48.832$ 7.101$ 8.1$ 8.2$
42.860$ 52.577$ 8.333$ 8.4$
42.351$ 40.783$ 8.457$ 9.8$ 5.4$
41.392$ 46.174$ 9.833$ 8.7$ 6.3$
39.794$ 40.274$ 6.191$ 5.2$ 4.1$
39.207$ 39.315$ 12.649$ 9.0$ 4.5$
39.080$ 35.620$ 12.043$ 6.8$ 4.0$
37.912$ 41.706$ 4.818$ 6.9$ 5.2$
37.231$ 35.436$ 6.205$ 6.0$ 4.7$
36.458$ 42.584$ 6.312$ 6.3$ 5.3$
Sorry for the formatting, i have no idea how to fix the formatting on this website.

Comment: im happy to send it to you via email. if you dont mind. it seems so messy here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rudimentary state machine in `awk` to do the first task:

```
pax> awk 'e==1{print $3;e=0}/ISSN:/{e=1}' inputFile1
0007-9235
```

It boils down to using an echo flag `e` to decide if the next line should be printed:

```
e==1    { print $3;
          e=0
        }
/ISSN:/ { e=1
        }
```

The first rule states: if `e` is one (it's zero before the script starts), print the third argument (the ISSN) then set `e` to zero to turn off echo.

The second rule simply turns on echo if it finds a line containing the `ISSN:` string so that, for the next line, the first rule will fire.

Keep in mind that's for the very specific format you've mentioned. Given that markup language tends to be a little more free-format, it may not work if your format changes. In that case, it's probably better to use a markup processing parser of some sort.

For the second task, `awk` is *also* the answer. To get the first two columns, just use:

```
pax> awk '{print $1" "$2}' inputFile2
162.500 107.740
54.420 52.426
45.661 48.832
42.860 52.577
42.351 40.783
41.392 46.174
39.794 40.274
39.207 39.315
39.080 35.620
37.912 41.706
37.231 35.436
36.458 42.584
```

although in your case it will be:

```
<your_current_grep_command> | awk '{print $1" "$2}'
```

Comment: I get the part where you make the conditions to trigger each other for multiple webpages, but an error occurred.
issn=$(awk 'e==1{print $3;e=0}/ISSN:/{e=1}'$i)
awk: 1: unexpected character '&'

Whereas the second part dosent work, it still showed all columns. 
Besides, these numbers are not the only one in the webpage, it were sourced using grep from different locations in the source code.

Comment: @Kin, you need to look into what's in `$i` because there's _no_ `&` in the code I gave. You may also want to check what you have since what you posted has no space between the `awk` arguments. In the second issue, the code I gave _does_ work based on the specs you gave, that's a real transcript of a run (ditto for the first one as well). If the spec has _more_ information, you should include that, preferably up front as you ask the question.

Comment: $i is a number, ranging 1-30.  The second part of the question, i had fixed it. the first part (issn) im still trying to fix and i came up with issn=$(grep "ISSN:" $i -A1)